# Jar giving null pointer exception java program

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, scale, executable-jar

I wrote a program to resize images for a friend it seems to be working if i compile it with eclipse it just resizes all the images where the program is being executed and creates a new directory there and saves the new scaled images into the folder.

But when i export it in java i get a null pointer exception the line that points to

```
 "  for (File file : allSubFiles) {"
```

help pelase

```
public class Sample {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String a = (Sample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    File dir = new File(a+"resized");
    dir.mkdir();

    System.out.println(a);
    File tempfile = new File(a); 
      File[] allSubFiles=tempfile.listFiles();

      for (File file : allSubFiles) {
          if(file.isDirectory())
          {

          }
          else
          {
              String temp = file.getAbsolutePath();
              String substr = temp.substring(temp.length() - 3);
              //System.out.println(substr);
              if(substr.equals("png") || substr.equals("gif") || substr.equals("jpg") || substr.equals("bmp") )
              {
              //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()+" is file");
              BufferedImage bufimage = ImageIO.read(file);
              BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(90, 90, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

              Graphics g = newImage.createGraphics();
              g.drawImage(bufimage, 0, 0, 90, 90, null);
              g.dispose();

              File outputfile = new File(a+"resized/"+file.getName());
              ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", outputfile);
              }
          }
      }


}

 }
```

Comment: Well, what does your debugging find?

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot comment (not enough reputation) here an answer.

Please try

```
Sample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().g‌​etPath()
```

If that does not work check if tempfile points to a valid directory (isDirectory()). What is the output of the program (the System.out)? The method listFiles() may return null in some circumstances.

From the javadoc for File ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)):

> Returns:
>           An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The
>   array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this
>   abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error
>   occurs**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will occur if the `tempfile` is not a directory. According to the `File` API, `listFiles()` will return null if the denoted file is not a directory. 
Also, because a jar file is a compressed package of class files and other files, you might try using the parent of `tmpFile`. While in eclipse, the class files are actually in a directory, but in a jar file they are not. `Sample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` may be returning the path of the jar file not the directory that the jar file is in. Using the parent file should be the directory that the jar is in. Also do the same when you create the new directory `dir`. Try something like this.

```
public class Sample {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String a = (Sample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    File tempfile = new File(a).getParentFile(); 
    File dir = new File(tempFile.getPath()+"resized");
    dir.mkdir();

    System.out.println(a);
    File[] allSubFiles=tempfile.listFiles();

    if(allSubFiles!=null){

      for (File file : allSubFiles) {
          if(file.isDirectory())
          {

          }
          else
          {
              String temp = file.getAbsolutePath();
              String substr = temp.substring(temp.length() - 3);
              //System.out.println(substr);
              if(substr.equals("png") || substr.equals("gif") || substr.equals("jpg") ||         substr.equals("bmp") )
              {
              //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()+" is file");
              BufferedImage bufimage = ImageIO.read(file);
              BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(90, 90, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

              Graphics g = newImage.createGraphics();
              g.drawImage(bufimage, 0, 0, 90, 90, null);
              g.dispose();

              File outputfile = new File(a+"resized/"+file.getName());
              ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", outputfile);
              }
          }
         }
        }


    }

}
```